# How do I restore my app (K-9 Mail) settings from an adb backup?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, backup, restore

I just installed Cyanogenmod on my Samsung Galaxy Note. Before doing so I created a backup with adb:

```
adb backup -all
```

For some of my apps I want to restore settings. Most importantly that would be K-9 Mail. Thus I unpacked the backup:

```
java -jar android-backup-extractor-20140630-bin/abe.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar
```

Then I deleted most folders which I don't want to restore but I did not delete `apps/apps/com.fsck.k9`. Then I packed the file again using android back extractor and ran `adb restore` after I installed K-9 Mail. I was prompted for consent on my phone which I accepted and I was told that the restore was successful. However when I start K-9 Mail I am just greeted with the default welcome screen as if no configuration would be present. I also tried the same with WhatsApp and Viber but both showed the same behaviour.

Next I tried to just copy the k9 mail settings folder using USB connection using a file manager (dolphin). But still no success.

Then I tried to copy the settings using `adb push apps/com.fsck.k9 /data/data/com.fsck.k9` (described by someone [here](https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/detail?id=549)) which failed with file or directory not found error. After further googling I tried again but ran `adb root` before and then that worked. However k9 still greets me with obviously no settings. Since the same source I googled for that idea stated something about a fix_permission script (where I have no idea where that comes from) I googled for fix_permission and found [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stericson.permissionfix) installed it and ran it. However still no change.

How is the restore done correctly?

Answer (score 1):

OK, some googleing later [I found](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/partial-adb-restore) [Titanum Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) and that it supports restoring selectively from adb backups. I copied the backup to my SD-Card and then restored using Titanum Backup and and just worked. (However I'd still be interested in what I missed in the first place).

Note however that the free version does not support restore from adb files.