# Pulling out app and data

Tags: adb

I incidentally broke the digitizer connector on the motherboard of my Nexus 10 tablet. I can still power on the tablet, but cannot do anything since the touchscreen is not working. I asked around a couple of repair stores, and was told that there is no easy fix for the connector. My question is: buying another connector or soldering the broken one would not be feasible?

If unfixable, I would like to pull the data out of the tablet, and move to another device. Since I can't use TitaniumBackup in this case, how can I extract each specific app and the data associated with that app so that I could transfer to a phone or another tablet via shell command adb? I could run 'adb backup...', but with that I don't know how to transfer the backup to another device.

My Nexus 10 is rooted, so some of apps are rooted and others are non-rooted, and the former seem to be anywhere on the phone. Also with TitaniumBackup, I know how to transfer the app and its data to another device. In this case, after pulling out the data, how do I move to another device? For example, I notice that some apps are stored under /data/data/ with multiple directories such as databases/, lib/, files/, shared_prefs/, etc. Can I directly move the whole directory tree over to another device?

Another question: the rooted apps seem to be installed as /data/app/com.***.***/base.apk. I tried to pull out base.apk, but it can't be installed properly on another device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Install a custom non-touch CWM recovery via the adb, make a full backup in it, pull the created backup out via "adb sideload" function in the recovery. Then, you can play with the total backup of your system, just rename "data.ext4.win000" (internal storage file) to "data.ext4.tar.000" (and other files in similar way) and open it in [FTKImager](http://accessdata.com/product-download) (even lite version is enough).

If you want just to reinstall the apps with their data on a new smartphone use [AppExtractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handyandy.appextractor) with your backup zip

Comment: Thanks for the help! Not so comfortable with installing a CWM recovery at this stage. Is there a solution through a total backup with 'adb backup -all ...' ?

Comment: adb backup -apk -shared -all -f C:\1.ab  will probably pull out everything, but I don't know how to avoid backuping everything.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/partial-adb-restore
You should probably search for help on xda forum.

Comment: I just realized that I could not run a backup through 'adb backup ...' because it requires that I unlock the screen and confirm the backup operation, which I cannot do because of the loss of touchscreen.

Comment: so I guess, cwm non-touch recovery is maybe one of the last options that you can try